# How to specify HttpWebRequest.Headers["Range"] in a PCL?

Tags: httpwebrequest, portable-class-library

I'm writing a progressive downloader as a Portable Class Library (Profile=24). It will support partial downloads of target files in chunks of bytes. HttpClient not being available, I'm going with HttpWebRequest, which has the AddRange method for partial downloads. But the method doesn't seem to be available from inside the PCL. So I set HttpWebRequest.Headers["Range"], but doing so throws the following ArgumentException:

"The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.\r\nParameter name: name"

That "appropriate property" seems to be HttpWebRequest.AddRange, but as I said it doesn't seem to be exposed from inside PCL. So I'm quite confused: what would be the right way of specifying the HttpWebRequest.Headers["Range"] in a PCL?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Did you managed to find the answer? if so please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the answer, but the following interface workaround worked for me:

Instead of creating the HttpWebRequest in my portable code, I defined the following custom interfaces:

```
public interface IMyRequest {
    [...]
    void AddRange(long from, long to);
}

public interface IMyRequestFactory {
    IMyRequest Create(string url);
}
```

Then, in my non-portable code, I created classes that implemented those interfaces:

```
public class MyRequestImp : IMyRequest {
    private readonly HttpWebRequest request;

    public MyRequestImp (string url) {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    }

    [...]

    public void AddRange(long from, long to) {
        request.AddRange(from, to);
    }
}

public class MyRequestFactoryImp: IMyRequestFactory {
    public IMyRequest Create(string url) {
        return new MyRequestImp(url);
    }
}
```

At some point at initialization time, my non-portable code is passing a MyRequestFactoryImp object to my portable library through the IMyRequestFactory interface. Since the HttpWebRequest was created outside the PCL, you have access to the full functionalities of the class.

Comment: What about the UWP case? It's not available in UWP either.